# Angular2 date pipe does not work in IE 11 and edge 13/14

Tags: datetime, angular, format, pipe, internet-explorer-11

I'm using Angular 2.0 final, and I have an incorrect format of dates when I add hours and minutes in the format string:

In the template of the component, I have:

```
<th id="lastexecution">{{dto.LastExecution | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</th>
```

The output date in IE 11 is:

```
2016-09-27 15:00:9/27/2016 3:53:46 PM:9/27/2016 3:53:46 PM
```

With 
    {{dto.LastExecution | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}

The output date in IE 11 is correct:

```
2016-09-27
```

Here is the components version I use in the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ima_sentinel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t ima_sentinel .",
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ima_sentinel",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "linqts": "^1.6.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "signalr": "^2.2.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "typescript-collections": "^1.1.9",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Comment: I tried adding <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.en"></script> in index.html for compatibility with IE but without result.

Comment: This is an open issue against Angular caused (it seems) by a bug in IE/Edge - I've had to create a moment-based workaround which I've posted in an answer below, hope that helps!

Comment: In Angular 5 this will be solved, follow an example with Angular 5 Beta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46218711/2290538

Answer (score 62, accepted):

UPDATE - The [Angular issue that causes this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9524) is resolved in Angular 5. If you can, I would recommend using that to avoid this problem.

If you are still using Angular 4 or older - as a workaround, I created a pipe to use the moment formatter instead of the Angular built-in one:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({
    name: 'datex'
})

export class DatexPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, format: string = ""): string {
        // Try and parse the passed value.
        var momentDate = moment(value);

        // If moment didn't understand the value, return it unformatted.
        if (!momentDate.isValid()) return value;

        // Otherwise, return the date formatted as requested.
        return momentDate.format(format);
    }
}
```

Which can then be used:

```
{{exampleDate | datex:'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'}}
```

The date you pass in should be something which moment can parse (see [the relevant moment documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)) and the format string is a moment, not angular, date formatting string, as [documented here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

I've tested this in IE11, Chrome and Firefox and it behaves consistently.

You'll need to ensure moment is added to your package.json as a dependency, e.g.:

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  // snip
  "dependencies": {
    // snip
    "moment": "^2.15.1",
    // snip
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    //snip
  }
}
```

... and ensure your systemjs.config.js is updated so it can locate moment:

```
map: { 
  'moment': 'npm:moment' 
} 
packages: { 
  moment: { main: './moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' } 
}
```

Comment: It results with the following error when executing the project: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/moment. I have no idea why it is looking for the the library at this place whereas it is located in node_modules/moment. I have no error at compile time.

Comment: Ok system.config.js was not updated by the package install. I had to add:
map: {
'moment': 'npm:moment' }
packages: {             moment: {
                main: './moment.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            } }

It works pretty well thank you!!!

Comment: It just gives another form of garbage as a result. 01/th/y for MM/dd/y.

Comment: @léon-pelletier I'm not sure that is a valid momentjs format string for what you're trying to achieve (e.g. dd in moment formats as a two-letter day of week abbreviation); check the momentjs documentation linked in the answer for valid moment format strings.

Comment: What I've done is to rewrite my formats to work with this pipe and momentjs. Working very well now. +1!

Comment: Updated following on from the comment-answer from @seven

Comment: ***Tip:** If anyone wants to add moment in app.module.ts, it's like this: `import { Moment } from 'moment';`

Comment: You should not use this anymore if you use Angular 5, where the problem with native date pipe is solved. Note, that adding moment.js adds more than 300Kb in parsed size to the production build (in Angular 5 and CLI 1.6.8).

Comment: Great point @OndraPeterka - I've updated the answer to make it clear that using Angular 5 is the best way to fix this issue :)

Answer (score 15):

From Angular2 DatePipe API Documentation.

"this pipe uses the Internationalization API. Therefore it is only reliable in Chrome and Opera browsers.

Comment: Are they crazy?.

Comment: It now looks like the Internationalization API is supported on all major browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=internationalization%20api

Answer (score 10):

If you are okay with showing AM/PM instead of 24 hour time, another valid workaround is to break the formatting into two, and use `shortTime` or `mediumTime` for displaying the time portion:

`{{dto.LastExecution | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}} {{dto.LastExecution | date:'shortTime'}}`

This should work in all major browsers, including IE and Edge.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.

Comment: This was awesome! Thanks! Do you know how to grab the timezone? Like CST or EST? (Z) doesn't seem to work

Comment: @cheesydoritosandkale https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#description - see the table at this link that shows the different formatting options. Upper case `Z` is the zone offset, e.g. `-0800`. I think lower case `z` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @AndrewMairose The problem is, It just doesn't work on IE =(

Comment: @cheesydoritosandkale try using `date:'longTime'` - that includes the zone and should work in IE

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the answer from @mark-hughes above, from the moment API documentation:

> date_expression | date[:format]
>
> expression is a date object or a number (milliseconds since UTC epoch)
>   or an ISO string

[Reference](https://www.angular.cn/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html)

So the value should be any type, and you can use `moment().isValid()` to check the value type

```
@Pipe({name: 'datex'})
export class DatexPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, format: string = ""): string {
       return moment(value).isValid()? moment(value).format(format) : value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this answer is more of a comment on my answer - it's a good point though!

Comment: yeah，Thank you for giving me the inspiration

Answer (score 2):

**Work in Angular 5.x**

In version 5.x of the Angular this problem is working correctly in Edge (v.38.14393.1066.0) and in IE (v.11.1198.14393.0), test in your version!

**Live example: [<kbd>Plunker Angular 5.x</kbd>](https://embed.plnkr.co/aFlDe8CDHi3fqttD1RSv/?show=app%2Fapp.component.ts&show=preview)**

---

> Related issue that solved the problem (if I found something inconsistent): https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9524

---

> [Answer that involves the entire operation of the Angular DatePipe.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37931071/2290538)

Comment: Hello i tried the link you gave for Plunker and is not working on IE 11. Is this related to the DatePipe issue?

Answer (score 2):

The below solution works fine in for IE11 and chrome. No need to create custom pipes.

```
 {{dto.createdTimeLocal | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}} {{dto.createdTimeLocal | date:'shortTime'}}
```

Comment: Do you know how to grab the timezone? Like CST or EST? (Z) doesn't seem to work on IE.

Comment: use moment.js, will filter the time zones

Answer (score 0):

**moment.js pipes for Angular**

Marks answer is great and it was what I was using till I found this simple solution that is well documented.

[moment.js pipes for Angular](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment)

This module works with Angular 2.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write format like this `{{date:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a}}`.
IE11 or EDGE getting issue with this format only.

Here are some alternatives:

Ex 1: new date and time:

```
var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
var time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

var datetime = date + " " + time;
```

Ex 2: Already you have a `datetime` and you want to convert. see below:

```
datetime = "3/23/2018 11:43:51 AM"
```

We can split the date and time.

```
var date = new Date(datetime).toLocaleDateString();
var time = new Date(datetime).toLocaleTimeString();

var splitdatetime = date + " " + time;
```

This is Angular4. it work fine for all browsers.