# Angular 2 import DatePipe and transform not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms, angular-filters

I am using Angular 2 to get exception free date, such a case I get '0000-00-00' date from server and throw exceptions so I followed Pipe for filter.

```
{{"2016-05-11" | dateFormat:task_.date_format}}
```

Pipe Code -

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { TaskService } from '../providers/taskService';

@Pipe({name: 'dateFormat'})
export class DateFormatPipe implements PipeTransform{


    constructor(public taskService: TaskService,private datePipe: DatePipe){}

    transform(value :any[],arg:any): any  {

        console.log("dateFormat value "+value+"\n arg "+arg);

        let format_ = this.taskService.getDateFormate(arg);
        console.log("format_ ",format_)
        let formatted = this.datePipe.transform(value, format_);
        console.log("formatted "+formatted);
        // if (value == this.taskService.getDateFormate(arg)) {
        return value;
        // }
    }
}
```

But it is not working , i just want that if proper date then return with selected i.e. yyyy-mm-dd, mm-dd-yyyy so on, otherwise return 0000-00-00.

Comment: you are returning value instead of formatted. Is the correct format gettng logged in the console?

Comment: I know, actually it is giving error, So I tried with formatted but it is giving Unknow DatePipe.

Comment: Do you have any modification for above code?

Comment: var datePipe:any = new DatePipe();  Throw Error - Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Comment: what do you need it to print for 0000?

Comment: why not put youe date print within ngIf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give variable type like

```
datePipeEn: DatePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
```

And don't forget '**en-Us**' which language code then use transform method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included your pipe in the bootstrap of your app.module file (declarations array)?

Check then the typo in your statement (guess Formate should be Format)
    let format_ = this.taskService.getDateFormate(arg);

Except this, are you aware that Angular2 has [it's own implementation of the Date pipe?](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) Additionally, as stated in the docs, if you're using Safari or older browsers you have to include the ECMAScript Internationalization API

Please check your variable naming convention (task_ doesn't look so good in my opinion...)

Comment: Actually, I have checked already. I Just want to get exception free , which is getting when I get "0000-00-00" from server and that time 'date:yyyy-mm-dd' or more throw exception "Invalid Time".

Comment: I was following - http://stackoverflow.com/a/37859544/6547558 & http://stackoverflow.com/a/35144872/6547558

Comment: var datePipe:any = new DatePipe(); Throw Error - Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. why?

Comment: You get an error because of your constructor signature: there are two injected service that you are not supplying. The Pipe should be declared in the declarations array in the app.module file, then imported and used. I don.t get the reason why you are trying to create a new DatePipe object