# How do I display the current date and time in a form

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form that should include current date and time what should I do to display them without using pipes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format date as dd/MM/yyyy in Angular 2 using pipes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754586/how-to-format-date-as-dd-mm-yyyy-in-angular-2-using-pipes)

Answer (score 17):

You can use the Angular2 [Date Pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html) to display a JavaScript Date object. Check the docs (linked) for the correct formatting that you are looking for.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'date-pipe',
  template: `<div>
    <p>Today is {{today | date}}</p>
    <p>Or if you prefer, {{today | date:'fullDate'}}</p>
    <p>The time is {{today | date:'jmZ'}}</p>
    <p>Finally the date and time is {{today | date:'short'}}</p>
  </div>`
})
export class DatePipeComponent {
  today: number = Date.now();
}
```

Comment: how do i call it in the html file ?

Comment: Instead of the `template` property of the component metadata you would use the `templateUrl` property and set the value equal to the relative path to the HTML file and put the code I have provide above inside of the file.