# Angular DateModel stopps working on adding name attribut

Tags: javascript, angular, mean

i want to have a dateField which gets filled, when the user enters the route. So this is the code i'm using:

**formular1.component.ts**

```
constructor(
    private validateService: ValidateService,
    private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private terminalService: TerminalService
  ) {
    this.todaysDate = new Date();
  }
```

**formular1.component.html**:

```
<input type="date" [ngModel]="todaysDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'" (ngModelChange)="todaysDate = $event" [value]="todaysDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'">
```

This works fine, the dateField gets filled with the correct value but i get a big error inside my console:

```
Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

      Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
      Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

Sounds simple... but when i add an `name="test"` attribute the dateField is no longer working and does not get filled with the date value - why?

Maybe someone can also tell me, how to get the correct time (summer / wintertime) here in germany we actually have +1 hour from the date i get by `New Date();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the date formating pipe

```
  <input type="date" name="todayDate" id="todayDate" [ngModel]="todaysDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="todaysDate = $event" [value]="todaysDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'">
```

If you want to convert to dd-mm-yyyy format [check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754586/how-to-format-date-as-dd-mm-yyyy-in-angular-2-using-pipes.)