# Date Formatting - Angular

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have a problem with setting the date and view it on the web page
here is my code:

.ts

```
public lastActivitateDate = new Date('10.10.2016');
```

.html

```
{{lastActivitateDate | date : 'dd.mm.yyyy'}}
```

and I get on the web page:
10.00.2016

so how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format date as dd/MM/yyyy in Angular 2 using pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754586/how-to-format-date-as-dd-mm-yyyy-in-angular-2-using-pipes)

Comment: it didn't help me :/

Comment: `mm` are minutes, month are `MM`.

Comment: @ShashankVivek not a duplicate, just a rookie mistake.

Comment: I thought that question will surely help him figure out whats wrong. :)

Comment: Try {{ lastActivitateDate | date:'d'}}/{{ lastActivitateDate | date:'MM'}}/{{ lastActivitateDate | date:'y'}}

Comment: @AravindS : `{{lastActivitateDate | date : 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}` is enough :)

Comment: That was to convey the OP in detail :)

Comment: @s66168 consider deleting your question once you have resolved your issue, as it is only helping you

Answer (score 3):

just change to **MM** instead of **mm**

mm provides minutes

MM provides months

**.ts**

**public lastActivitateDate = new Date('10.10.2016');**

**.html**

**{{lastActivitateDate | date : 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}**

you will get proper answer on your screen. If you need some more diffrent date time format go through momentjs.

momentjs provides nice and diffrent format to use date and time. Here, below is the link.

[momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)