# convert date to DD/MM/YYYY in ionic 4 + Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a problem with picker-date;

- when I choose the date from the picker and submit the form...
- in my list-view, the date showing with this format:
- Sun Nov 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
- as seen in the [screenshot][1].
- I want to show the date like this format: 03/11/2019

how I can do it ??

`list-ech.page.html`:

```
<ion-header>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col size="12" size-sm="8" offset-sm="2">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let Echeancee of loadEcheances" #slidingItem="">
      <ion-item [routerLink]="['/', 'list-echeances', Echeancee.id]" detail>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <ion-img [src]="Echeancee.chkImage"></ion-img>
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <h3>{{ Echeancee.BenefNamee }}</h3>
        <p>  {{ Echeancee.DateDuee }}</p>        
      </ion-item>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
</ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format date as dd/MM/yyyy using pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754586/format-date-as-dd-mm-yyyy-using-pipes)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this in your view

```
{{valueDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Another format can be found [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)