# I want to convert Date to dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: angular

```
Get(AgrTempId) {
    this.AgreementsService.GetAgreementTemp(AgrTempId).subscribe((res: BaseResponse) => {
      debugger;
      
      this.agrTempValidFrom = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(new Date(res.data["validFrom"]), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      this.agrTempValidTo = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(new Date(res.data["validTo"]), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
     

    },
      (error) => {
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use moment for that

```
moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

in your case you can use this way

```
  this.agrTempValidFrom = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(moment(new Date(res.data["validFrom"])).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  this.agrTempValidTo = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(moment(new Date(res.data["validTo"])).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Comment: you imported moment?

Comment: There is no error but it appears like this mm-dd-yyyyy

Comment: `MM-DD-YYYY` You can try this. You can refer to the moment.js docs if you need more info

Comment: the format in Api is yyyy-MM-dd . i can't change it

Comment: You can format any date format string to upper case. `"yyyy-MM-dd".toUpperCase()`

Comment: What will be the benefit?

Comment: It will be same everytime irrespective of the case followed in the api. It supports all the formats which we use in the moment.js

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Format date as dd/MM/yyyy using pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754586/format-date-as-dd-mm-yyyy-using-pipes)
This answer was useful to me :

```
var ddMMyyyy = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(),"dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: you can use a language identifier to highlight the code and make it better to read