# How to provide LOCALE_ID from an observable in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-providers

In Angular 2, in order to localize date pipe you need to provide `LOCALE_ID`. I have a service `LocaleService` that exposes `locale$: Observable<string>` which implements `BehaviorSubject<string>`. I don't want to add any state to this service, I want it to be completely reactive. How can I obtain information from this service when providing `LOCALE_ID`?

Answer (score 1):

Solution with LOCALE_ID is great if you want to set the language for your app once. But it doesn’t work, if you want to change the language during runtime. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45624434/2598453).

Answer (score 0):

A pipe can return an Observable.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { LocaleService } from 'shared/locale.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { formatDate } from 'somelibrary';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Pipe({
  name: 'myDate',
  pure: false
})
export class MyDatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private localeService: LocaleService) { }

  transform(date: string): Observable<String> {
    return this.localeService.locale$.map(locale => formatDate(date, locale));
  }
}
```

Comment: While this is a solution, I take it as OP wants to know how to set LOCALE_ID and keep on using standard date pipe