# Angular4: Locale for a user

Tags: angular, internationalization

I want to have a LoginForm and after this user enters the application - either with German or English usage. As far as I understand I can set in the `app.module.ts` something like

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de-DE' },...]
```

But that is at the startup and not when the LoginForm was already displayed :-/ Is there a way to change the locale for the whole app? (Not only for a specific component!) - Would be great if the translations could be changed as well on the fly. Any hints how to achieve? I only found the above way to deal with.

Answer (score 13):

I followed the answer from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39344889/325868) and I have the following solution:

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [...
     {provide: LOCALE_ID,
      deps: [SettingsService],      // some service handling global settings
      useFactory: getLanguage  // returns locale string
    }
  ]
  // ...
})
export class AppModule { }
// the following function is required (for Angular 4.1.1!!!)
export function getLanguage(settingsService: SettingsService) {
  return settingsService.getLanguage();
}
```

***Note:*** The usage of an extra function prevents the error `Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function` !!!!

and I create the class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SettingsService {
  currentLang: string;

  constructor() {
    this.currentLang = 'en';
  }

  setLanguage(lang: string) {
    this.currentLang = lang;
  }
  getLanguage() {
    return this.currentLang;
  }
}
```

which changes the `LOCALE_ID` on the fly :-)

Comment: It doesn't work for the date Pipe, the months in MMM format stays in the default lang.

Comment: Sorry the late reply - but this works on my side, e.g. `{curDate|date:'medium'}} <--> {{curDate| date:'MMM' }} <-->  {{curDate| date:'MMMM' }} <-->` works perfectly ... don't know where/how you perceive the prob...

Comment: Whenever I change the current language, while all the `| translate` update correctly, the months in `| date` won't update

Comment: read the documentation, they've made `date` immutable to save on calculations, you should change the reference (create new `date` I guess) so it will trigger the change (haven't tried this yet)

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

- use local storage to store the locale (eg. 'fr')
- load the associated translation file in main.ts (eg. messages.fr.xlf)
- set the LOCALE_ID in app.module.ts

To change the locale

- set the new locale in local storage
- refresh the app

main.ts

```
declare const require;

const locale = localStorage.getItem('locale');
const translation = require(`raw-loader!./locale/messages.${locale}.xlf`)

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  providers: [
    {provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: translation},
    {provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf'}
  ]
});
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: localStorage.getItem('locale')}
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: the approach looks interesting. But what is the `require`d `raw-loader!`? Is this a package which needs to be installed? Or a default Angular package?

Comment: It's "A loader for webpack that lets you import files as a string." https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader

Comment: raw-loader is included by default in angular-cli

Comment: Ah, I see what you were asking now LeO. Sorry for the hasty response.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing in app.module.ts is the right way to do this and for the whole app:

```
@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de-DE'}
  ]
  // ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But unfortunately I don't think that it's possible to change it on the fly.