# Angular (v4) DatePipe with UTC datetime as local time

Tags: angular, datetime, iso8601

Unlike newer versions of Angular, [Angular 4 DatePipe](https://v4.angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) doesn't seem to support passing in a timezone as a parameter.

I have a backend service returning an ISO 8601 formatted datetime string without timezone (e.g., `2018-12-04T19:01:50.062`) -- stored and returned as UTC.

Using `DatePipe`, how can I show the datetime as the user's local time?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Angular 4's [`DatePipe`](https://v4.angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) supports the [UTC zone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)) suffix ('Z'), so if the value you pass to the pipe is a UTC datetime, then your backend service can return your datetime with the 'Z' zone designator or you can append `Z` and it will show the date time in the user's local time.

For example,

```
<span class="date">{{ value + 'Z' | date:'short' }}</span>
```

---

**NOTE:** You need to make sure you are providing Angular's LOCALE_ID dynamically to the correct locale (import the exported provider into your app module), if you want `DatePipe` to use the user's browser settings:

```js
export class WindowRefService {
    public getWindow(): Window {
        return window;
    }
}

export function languageFactory(windowRef: WindowRefService): string {
  return windowRef.getWindow().navigator.language;
}

export const localeProvider = {
  provide: LOCALE_ID,
  deps: [WindowRefService],
  useFactory: languageFactory
};
```

See other questions on `LOCALE_ID`: [Angular4: Locale for a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918376/angular4-locale-for-a-user)

Comment: Flawless! Thank you for this simple solution!