# How do I convert and display a UTC DateTime to the browsers local time?

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, utc, luxon

I need to show a UTC date time in the users browser as the users(browser) local time.

Ex. 04:52 UTC -> 09:52 PST (if browser/user is in Los Angeles)

as PST is -7 hours from UTC

I have no requirement, it can be done in Javascript, typescript, or using Luxon, which I currently use across my project.

Comment: Have you come across this. Basically, you would like to convert a datetime stored in utc to a specific time zone --> https://www.thisdot.co/blog/how-to-handle-time-zones-using-datetime-and-luxon/

Comment: ya I saw that, but it assumes you know the time zone you want to set. I want to take a dateTime that's UTC and display it to the user in their times zone. Doesn't your browser know the time zone! So can't you set the UTC to the browsers time zone? Ex. If I'm in Los Angelas I set my UTC dateTime to -7

Comment: Do you have a complete date and time stamp, or only a time?

Comment: There are _many_ answers already here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6525538/476

Comment: I have both date and times.

Comment: What are the odds that the example you provided has the exact same time as my example above???

Comment: Huh, waddaya know?! So, question answered? Should I refund your bounty?

Comment: if u want, if I can close or delete it I will.

Comment: actually this link provided me the best solution for Angular - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53622231/1186050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best solution for me using Angular. Just add the 'Z'

`{{(transfer.createdDate + 'Z' | date)}}`

[link is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53622231/1186050)