# Angular2 Invalid language tag: en_US

Tags: javascript, angular, date

I would like to display a date format based on a different locale. Ideally one that I can decide upon after a query to a remote server. (The value to be put in the date field is retrieved in this same query).
I'm trying to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904683/how-to-set-locale-in-datepipe-in-angular2?answertab=votes#tab-top) but am getting an error: `Invalid language tag: en_US`

code:

```
@NgModule({...
  providers: [
{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "en_US"}
],
...
```

I'm obviously missing some kind of resource, but I have no idea what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the question you linked it has:`"en-US"`

However you have:`"en_US"`