# How to set locale bs in DatePipe in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

```
providers:  [  { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "bs-BA" }]
```

I'm trying to add this to get month name in bosnian but is not working. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you look at this post

[set locale in datepipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39344889/7261317)

i think the above post working fine,can you check that

Answer (score 0):

in your module module

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

@NgModule({
 imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
 declarations: [ AppComponent ],
 bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
 providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'bs-BA' },
],
})

export class AppModule { }
```

in your component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  {{date | date: 'd MMMM y'}}
 `
 })
 export class AppComponent {

    date = new Date(1988, 2, 15);
 }
```

[image: This for "bs-BA"]

[image: This for "en-US"]

Comment: I dont get month name

Comment: MO3 is not month name...its nothing on bosnian langauge

Comment: oh i think "MO3" month name, let check and let you know