# Changing locale in Angular at runtime?

Tags: javascript, angular, internationalization, locale

I was doing some research on changing Angular locale at runtime and found this thread: [How to set locale in DatePipe in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904683/how-to-set-locale-in-datepipe-in-angular-2) .
Is it still the case that there is no way to change locale at runtime?  I have an application that features several pipes to format number, date and language depending on the locale, but implementing many custom pipes for each locale -- rather than having the ability to change it during runtime--seems ridiculous.
What solutions would you purpose?

Answer (score 7):

I bet you are searching for this because today you're upgrading `@angular/material` to `beta.10` and the DatePicker now uses `LOCALE_ID`, isn't it? I'm looking for an alternative too and had no luck.

Angular 4 i18n approach is based on the compiler, generating different bundles for different languages, so a `runtime` solution seems not supported by that architecture. There's work being done in Angular 6 compiler to support `runtime` translation changes.

For the moment, I like `ngx-translate` approach, they seem to subscribe to lang changes and update the DOM nodes registered with the Directive, and I'm planning to build my own DateFormat pipe based on their [TranslateDirective](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/master/src/translate.directive.ts), but about services and components using the `LOCALE_ID`, I think there's no chance to change their behavior at runtime. Probably there are new exported resources for extension and customization (I did read something in the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)), so we may need to go deep into the components we want to translate.

If you take the `ngx-translate` approach, let's share stuff at github to build new pipes ;)