# Dynamically change provider

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have such page module:

```
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
...

@NgModule({
  imports [
  ...
  ],
  declarations [
  ...
  ],
  entryComponents [
  ...
  ],
  providers [
  {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: localStorage.getItem('localization')}
  ]
})
```

And when I come to page, my `LOCAL_ID` gets the value from `localStorage`. But if my item in `locaLstorage` gets change, `LOCAL_ID` is not updating. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This question may help to solve your problem.
[Changing locale in Angular at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962928/changing-locale-in-angular-at-runtime)

I use ngx-translate to work with different languages in Angular and I think is the best soution.