# Pass language with Date Pipe in Angular 2 HTML template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, date-pipe

In Angular2, we can format the date using DatePipe using typescript as:

new DatePipe(navigator.language || 'en-US').transform(mydate, 'medium')

But, I want to do this on HTML side. I read that I can do like this:

mydate | date:'medium'

But, this is still not taking care of localization, as in, its not passing the language. How do I modify the usage of pipe in my HTML so I can pass the language also?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904683/how-to-set-locale-in-datepipe-in-angular-2

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `DatePipe` you are limited to the defaults provided there, but if you want to set the locale in you template, whether it's a literal or comes from a variable, you can define a custom pipe like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({name: 'dateWithLocale'})
export class DateWithLocalePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(){}
  transform(value: string, locale: string, pattern: string): number {
    return new DatePipe(locale).transform(value, pattern);
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
{{time | dateWithLocale: 'en-US' : 'short'}}
```

You can see the working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/gFaD55fgucjNeJaFPfF2?p=preview).