# How to translate date in ionic 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

My problem is this: I cannot translate the date into another language in the html file.

I use `ionic 3`. This is my code:

```
{{(valeur | date:‘fullDate’) | translate }}
```

The result is this:

```
Monday, October, 30,2017
```

Presently I use the language `fr-FR` and I would like the result to appear like

```
Lundi, 30 octobre 2017
```

Answer (score 3):

This [Question and Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904683/how-to-set-locale-in-datepipe-in-angular-2) appear to cover the issue.

[corrola's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495244/corolla)

As of Angular2 RC6, you can set default locale in your app module, by adding a provider:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "fr-FR" }, //replace "en-US" with your locale
        //otherProviders...
    ]
})
```

The Currency/Date/Number pipes should pick up the locale. LOCALE_ID is an OpaqueToken, to be imported from angular/core.

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
```

For a more advanced use case, you may want to pick up locale from a service. Locale will be resolved (once) when component using date pipe is created:

```
{
    provide: LOCALE_ID,
    deps: [SettingsService],      //some service handling global settings
    useFactory: (settingsService) => settingsService.getLanguage()  
    //returns locale string
}
```