# Locales in Angular 5

Tags: angular, localization

I am new to the concept of locales. From what I could understand, I made an Angular 4 app that would read the locale from the browser using the `navigator.language()` API and supply to Angular's pipes. Since all of this changes with v5, I have some questions around migration.

My understanding is that the list here: https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/common/locales provides a list of locales that can be supplied to `registerLocaleData()`.

Thus, I can `import localeEnIn from '@angular/common/locales/en-IN'` and `registerLocaleData(localeEnIn)` to activate the locale.

To automatically load the app in the browser's locale, I will have to use the `navigator.language()` API to get the locale ID (say "en-GB") and call `registerLocaleData(localeEnGb)` where `localeEnGb` is imported from the list above. Can this be automated without me having to specify all locales?

There are locales like `en` and `de`. Should I split the response of `navigator.language()` and supply just "en"?

Comment: fyi it's navigator.language, a property not a function

Answer (score 1):

This is so problematic also for me:

Please find here an import of ALL the Angular 5 locales :
http://iteration.info/Sharing/AllAngular5Locales.rtf

I hope in Angular 6 will do :

```
import locales($var);
```

Answer (score 0):

To see a list of available locales, you can install a new angular app, and add localisation support:

```
ng add @angular/localize
```

Then look in your app's folder for a listing:

```
\node_modules\@angular\common\locales\
```