# Angular 4 datepicker locale not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datepicker

I'm using [ng-pick-datetime](https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker) UI component for the date picker. I disabled `readonly` mode, so that the input is active for typing with keyboard.

```
<owl-date-time name="client_birthday" #client_birthday="ngModel"
    [placeHolder]="'DD.MM.YYYY'"
    [locale]="ru"
    [(ngModel)]="client.client_birthday"
    [type]="'calendar'"
    [dataType]="'string'"
    [dateFormat]="'DD.MM.YYYY'"
    [readonlyInput] ="false"
    [autoClose] ="true"
    [inputId]="'client_birthday'"                                                   
></owl-date-time>
```

I try to apply `RU` locale using `date-fns`:

```
ru: any;
ruLocale = require('date-fns/locale/ru');
ngOnInit() {     
    this.ru = {
        firstDayOfWeek: 1,
        dayNames: [...],
        dayNamesShort: [...],
        monthNames: [...],
        monthNamesShort: [...],
        dateFns: this.ruLocale
    };
}
```

When I type into the input with `dd.mm.yyyy` format, the picker makes day as a month and month as a day, and the year is ok. So, the only format it recognizes is `mm.dd.yyyy`, which seems to be `us` locale. My calendar language changed as expected, but is it possible to configure date format for `RU` as well?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have u installed date-fns too?

Comment: @RajkumarRathi, yes

Comment: https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker#localization does this solve problem

Comment: @thakurinbox, this is the same I did

Answer (score 6):

It seams unable to do what you want when input date by typing on input box of ng-pick-datetime.
I went through the implementation of the ng-pick-datetime Component.
When typing, given input converting to date object by using https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/parse 
Here is the implementation
picker.component.ts/src/picker.component.ts Line-1177 Method-parseToDate

```
/**
     * Parse a object to Date object
     * @param {any} val
     * @return {Date}
     * */
    private parseToDate( val: any ): Date {
        if (!val) {
            return;
        }

        let parsedVal;
        if (typeof val === 'string') {
            parsedVal = parse(val, this.dateFormat, this.now);
        } else {
            parsedVal = val;
        }

        return isValid(parsedVal) ? parsedVal : null;
    }
```

https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker has used  "date-fns": "^2.0.0-alpha.7g" on package json. It has a argument to pass the date format to parse date.

```
parsedVal = parse(val, this.dateFormat, this.now);
```

But latest version of date-fns: "^1.29.0",   Do not have parmeter to pass the date format. So it fails on your project too. Please read https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/parse

```
parse(argument, [options])
```

Comment: Good point, thanks. Maybe you could suggest other date picker plugin that supports date formatting?

Comment: I am suggesting you to edit ng-pick-datetime code to match for your requirement and use it on your solution. I haven't used any datepicker matching with your requirement. https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker this is supporting to formatting but not when type on input.  If my answer help you to solve your problem please vote me up ;).

Answer (score 2):

similar to this:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "ru-ru"},
    //otherProviders...
  ]
})
```

have a look at this
[How to set locale in DatePipe in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904683/how-to-set-locale-in-datepipe-in-angular-2/45624434#45624434)

Comment: IF you're going for a 50 point bounty, I'd recommend providing the _specific_ LOCALE_ID, rather than suggesting they follow the model and adjust themselves...

Comment: LOCALE_ID is a constant provider token from angular core. That is the correct value.

Comment: that didn't work unfortunately. It seems to be used for pipes only