# Angular2 Time incorrect when I insert a record. How can I impost GTM+2.00?

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, time, localtime

In my app I have a page were can insert a record with a property 'performedOn'. when insert record whit a date(24/07), the time is 00.00am but the GTM is -2.00 infact when save, date change in (23/07 at 22.00pm).
How can I change time??
Thank!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the locale or just the timezone.

- You can change the locale or timezone of your current date object and
  transform it manually to your needs by using a [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe).

First you need to import DatePipe in your app.module file

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

Add it to the providers in @NgModule.

```
providers: [DatePipe]
```

In component.ts:

Import into the component.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

Add it to the constructor.

```
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe){}
```

Then you can do something like this. This would transform the date to the timezone GMT+2.00.

```
dateObject = new Date();

formattedDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.dateObject, 'full', '+200');
```

You can see the example live [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sykgvz).

To clarify. [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#parameters) has 3 arguments (format, timezone, locale) and you can call them like this.

```
this.myPipe.transform(myData, arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

You can also format with the Pipe in the html like this:

```
{{ myData | myPipe: 'arg1':'arg2':'arg3'... }}
```

So to make the right date format you can play around with the arguments.

If you want to make global changes you can check:

- [Setting up your app locale](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#setting-up-the-locale-of-your-app)
- You can also check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904683/how-to-set-locale-in-datepipe-in-angular-2/45624434)

Answer (score 0):

Use **moment.js** for date and time, which gives the various date and time functionalities as Follows:

https://momentjs.com/

moment.js have different methods to get the time and date in necessary format.

today = moment()

If you want specific date format,Then you use like

```
today=moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

`console.log('Today Date with format  e.g 24/07/2018`  `:',moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'))`

You need to install moment by using following cmd :

Step 1 : **npm i moment --save**

Step 2 : **import * as moment from 'moment';** `//in your component code.`

Comment: I have an error. my code:
this.wtr.performedOn = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');
'this.wtr.performedOn' show an error: 'type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'

Comment: Check your variable data type e.g : this.wtr.performedOn . try to make it e.g currentDate:any ,then you use as this.currentDate= moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');

Comment: Time remain -2.00