# Missing local date for local fr angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive, internationalization

I am on angular 5 project i wanted to show the date using date pipes, i used this code

```
<p class="creationDate" i18n>Date de création :{{today | date: 'medium'}}</p>
```

It worked good but i want that the date is written in french but the problem that is in english.
In the ts file i aded those lines:

```
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
import localeFrExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/fr';
registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr-FR', localeFrExtra);
```

Can someone help me please.

Comment: Did you import the french locale data?

Comment: yes i imported  import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
import localeFrExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/fr';
registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'id-ID', localeFrExtra);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set locale in DatePipe in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904683/how-to-set-locale-in-datepipe-in-angular-2)

Comment: @Mat What is `'id-ID'`?

Comment: of sorry import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
import localeFrExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/fr';
registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr-FR', localeFrExtra);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your app.module.ts // main.ts

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';

**registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'en');**
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-j5kczh)