# Angular date format based on locale

Tags: angular, date, format, date-format

I have an Angular 2 application in which I have few inputs of type date. By default those dates are displayed in the format  `MM/dd/YYYY`. I need them to be in the format `dd.MM.YYYY`. I have fond out that this can be set in the `app.module.ts` so that you specify the region that have this format. 
The piece of code that should  do the job is:

```
@NgModule({
 .
 .
 .
  providers: [AuthGuard, {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'sl'}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

This is the HTML part which I want to format

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label>Birth date:</label>
    <div class="form-group input-group">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text">
          <i class="fa fa-birthday-cake" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
      <input class="form-control" type="date" [ngModel]="birthDate" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Do anyone have any ide why this is not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set locale in DatePipe in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904683/how-to-set-locale-in-datepipe-in-angular-2)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: Didn't found this but this solution still doen't work for me.

Comment: Any error message ?

Comment: No. No error. All compiles as it should just it doesn't format the date as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research I have found out that we cannot change the display format of `<input type="date">`. The only way to change it is to change the chrome settings to use the local language. In order to archive what I was trying to, you must use a date picker. 

Here it's an example: 
[Angulat material date picker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) 
And for a more detailed read about the Chrome answer to my question, here is the link (the note is from 2012 but it still works as it was working back then):
[Chrome and input type date](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome?hl=en)
Thank you all for your time