# How to properly use datePipe in Angular

Tags: angular, date, pipe

It's been a few hours that I'm trying to figure this out.
I'm trying to simply convert a timestamp `Timestamp(seconds=1555755972, nanoseconds=393000000)` into a normal date dd/mm/yyyy.

I'm getting a list of documents from firestore, then I pass them through my component:

```
export class MissionComponent implements OnInit {

  missions: Mission[];
  mission: any = {};

  constructor(
      private missionService: MissionService,
      private datePipe: DatePipe)
 {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.missionService.getMissions().subscribe(data => {
      this.missions = data.map(e => {
        return{
          id: e.payload.doc.id,
          ...e.payload.doc.data()
        } as Mission;
      });
    });
}
```

and then I show few fileds thorugh a for cycle in the html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let mission of missions">
                                            ..
                                            <td>{{mission.dataRitiro.toDate() }}</td>
                                            <td>{{mission.dataConsegna.toDate() }}</td>
...
```

`mission.dataRitiro` gives me `Timestamp(seconds=1555755972, nanoseconds=393000000)`

If I'm converting the `mission.dataRitiro` with `.toDate()` I'm getting `Wed Apr 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale)`

untill here everithing works, but I want to get `03/04/2019`, so, searching in internet I've found the method `datePipe`, I just need to  write `mission.dataRitiro.toDate() | date: 'dd/mm/yyyy'` but if I wirte it inside the html I just get a blank field  and in console I'm getting this error

```
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Missing locale data for the locale "it-IT".' for pipe 'DatePipe'
    at...
```

but in my app.module I've imported 
`import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';`
and inserted inside the providers 
`{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "it-IT" }`

So at this point I really don't know what to do.
Thankyou guys.

Comment: just for your information, you are coding with Angular, not angularjs ;)

Comment: lol, sorry! I'm getting a little confused

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/i18n#i18n-pipes

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904683/how-to-set-locale-in-datepipe-in-angular-2