# Angular DatePipe iso pattern based on locale or language

Tags: angular, date

Angular DatePipe does not look to have some way to format date patterns based on a pattern and change the pattern based on the language.

The default when using DatePipe is medium. But i wwant to use this format yyyy-MM-dd for english. However, other countries like Italy use this format dd.mm.yy

So if I do this:

```
formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', this.translateService.currentLang);
```

and the language is it

inside, it should format the date with the pattern dd.mm.yy but that piece of code will still output it with format yyyy-MM-dd

Is this a limitation? Is the best recourse to use moment?

Comment: I believe a simple approach is to use `input type='datetime-local' ...>` that will set the date format based on user locale

Comment: how about if its basic output? like in {{ mydate | date .... }} is that possible?

Comment: i believe this post should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904683/how-to-set-locale-in-datepipe-in-angular-2