# Add 2 decimal points & thousand separator to input value Angular

Tags: angular

I want to show 2 decimal places & a thousand separators to my input tag. I have tried few methods but failed. following is my code

**HTML**

```
<input  type="number" class="form-control" [value]='totalCollected'  readonly>
```

**Component.ts**

```
export class PaymentListComponent implements OnInit {
  totalCollected = 0.00;
  totalOutstanding = 0.00;
}

  calculateTotal(){
    this.totalCollected = this.psList.reduce((accumulator, current) => accumulator + current.CashValue + current.ChequeValue + current.CrediNoteValue, 0)
    console.log('collected' + this.totalCollected)
    this.totalOutstanding = this.psList.reduce((accumulator, current) => accumulator + current.NetValue - (current.CashValue + current.ChequeValue + current.CrediNoteValue), 0)
    console.log('Outstanding' + this.totalOutstanding)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is

**HTML**
needs to use type as "`text`" & `[value]` to `[ngModel]`

```
<input  type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="totalCollected | number : '1.2-2'"  readonly>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`DecimalPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe).
Its parameteres are [`digitsInfo`](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#digitsinfo) which specfies format and `locale` which determines thousands separator.
`locale` should be set to the one which have a thousand separator what you need.
In the below example 2 decimal places and a space as separator will be displayed.

```html
<input  type="number" class="form-control" [value]="totalCollected | number: '6.2-2' : 'fr-FR'"  readonly>
```

Comment: this is not working for my code. get an error in console `The specified value "101,510.6" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.`

Comment: Configure the first digit in the format (it's minimum number of integer digits before the decimal point) as you need.
In your case it looks like the 6 would be enough.
I've updated the example. Pls, take a look

Comment: Still getting an error in console `ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Missing locale data for the locale "fr-FR".' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'` . and the value isn't showing in the input field

Comment: You need to import locale. See the following answer how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/48409743/12488082